# Call model in app.blade.php Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, model

```
@foreach (App\Category::orderBy('name')->get() as $category)
                <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{$category->name}} <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/')}}/{{ $category->name }}">All {{ $category->name }}</a></li>
                    @foreach (App\Subcaterogy::where('Category_name', $category->name)->orderBy('name')->get() as $subcategory)
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/')}}/{{ $subcategory->category}}/{{ $subcaterogy->name }}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a></li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </li>
        @endforeach
```

I have this code in my app.blade.php (my standard layout). I get this error: FatalErrorException in AliasLoader.php line 63:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

But I am only getting this error on the login and register page (standard Laravel authentication), the code works perfectly on all the other pages. On the other hand the login page works perfectly when i delete this part of the code from app.blade.php. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can change the value on your `php.ini` file; set ir to 500, like this: `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500`

Comment: 255 was also enough, thanks! But am I doing something wrong? Or is 100 a (very) low value?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code...it is just a limit imposed by another application(xdebug in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the line `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 255` (like Hackerman said) to the php.ini file solved my problem.